# Unable to create service account. "Already exists", but can't be found

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, service-accounts, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install Helm as [described here](https://github.com/ahmetb/gke-letsencrypt/blob/master/10-install-helm.md).
But when I'm doing `kubectl create serviceaccount -n kube-system tiller`
 I get a message saying *Error from server (AlreadyExists): serviceaccounts "tiller" already exists*. But I can't see it when I visit https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam nor https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts. How can that be? I had just made sure I was working the correct cluster:

`cloud container clusters get-credentials my-cluster
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for my-cluster.`

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing Google service accounts and Kubernetes service accounts.

`kubectl get serviceaccount -n kube-system tiller -o yaml`

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/